# Background color in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, background-color

In my GridView I have the column name `Switch` which can contain in each row, three different values; L, B and T.

You can associate a different background color according to values L, B and T ?

For example when the row contain in column name `Switch` the value L the background color is yellow, when the value B the background color on the row is green and the value T the background color on the row is red.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can do this on rowdatabound event of the grid view. This event will trigger for each row of grid, means you will have access of each row with data. so you can check the value and paint your row background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, if the grid is present in a windows form,

```
dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells["Switch"].Value) == "L").ToList()
                  .ForEach(x => x.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Your suggestion should be included in RowDataBound event, rigth?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in `RowsAdded` Event

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (String.CompareOrdinal(row.Cells["Switch"].Value.ToString(), "L") == 0)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (String.CompareOrdinal(row.Cells["Switch"].Value.ToString(), "B") == 0)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```